# Is educational transcript mandatory for Australian skill assessment PR visa process?

Tags: australia, skilled-migration, pr

I want to apply for Australian PR visa as Skilled Migrant in the visa subclass 190 or 489.
Hence I have to assess my skill with ACS, but I have all the documents except the *Education Transcript*. I am confused whether the transcript is mandatory for Skill assessment?
Will a scanned colour copy of all the results (documents) work for assessment?

Answer (score 1):

You need ECA to apply for PR and organizations that run ECA need your academic transcripts.

I am not sure if skill assessment process requires transcripts, however I am quite certain that you need that for ECA.

So I would like to suggest to prepare your transcripts first.

ECA : Educational Credential Assessment